# Python regex to find special characters between delimiters

Tags: python, regex

Given a string, I want to make a regex that only matches an invalid, specific character, e.g. a "semicolon," that is *not* found within brackets or parentheses.  I am able to write a pattern that matches the opposite case, but how do I invert (e.g. `^`) the pattern?

**EDIT**: I should note, I need a general solution where n-length characters can exist between the semicolon and delimiter; not only zero-width matches.

```
>>> invalid = '2#2;a,a [4,4;b/b]'
>>> valid = '(2#2;a,a) [4,4;b/b]'
>>> pattern = r'(\(.+?\;.+?\))|(\[.+?\;.+?\])'      # finds valid cases; want the opposite

# Result
>>>bool(re.findall(pattern, invalid))                
True                                              # overlooks the invalid subset '2;a'
>>> not re.findall(pattern, valid)
True

# Desired result
>>>bool(re.findall(pattern_inverse, invalid))
True
>>> bool(re.findall(pattern_inverse, valid))
False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use alternation operator. The captured `;` must the one present outside of those brackets.

```
>>> import re
>>> invalid = '2;a [4;b]'
>>> valid = '(2;a) [4;b]'
>>> pattern = r'(?:\([^()]*;[^()]*\)|\[[^\[\]]*\;[^\[\]]*\])|(;)'
>>> re.findall(pattern, invalid)
[';', '']
>>> re.findall(pattern, valid)
['', '']
>>> any(re.findall(pattern, invalid))
True
>>> any(re.findall(pattern, valid))
False
```

OR

```
>>> pattern = r';(?![^()]*\)|[^\[\]]*\])'
>>> any(re.findall(pattern, invalid))
True
>>> any(re.findall(pattern, valid))
False
>>> re.findall(pattern, invalid)
[';']
>>> re.findall(pattern, valid)
[]
>>>
```

Comment: cant you just call `any(re.findall(...))` to do the same effect as your list comp

Comment: or `;(?![^()]*\)|[^\[\]]*\])`

Comment: It's still unclear what is happening here: `[^()]*\)`

Comment: `[^()]*`, this would match any character but not of ( or ), zero or more times.`[^..]` called negated character class..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative lookahead and lookbehind. To find examples of `;` not followed by a letter and square bracket you can do this:

```
;(?![a-z]\])
```

Adding a lookbehind gives you something like this:

```
(?<!\[[0-9]);(?![a-z]\])
```

There are some restrictions on what you can do in the lookbehind - in particular using "*" or "+" quantifiers is not possible.

An alternative, if you're happy for your regular expression to match the whole invalid section is to use something like this. You could then use a capturing group to extract the semi-colon if required.

```
(?<=^|\s)[^(\[]*;[^)\]]*(?=\s|$)
```

Comment: You are right.  Lookarounds work for this particular case, but I need a general solution that is not limited by zero-width matches.  I'll try to edit the question to reflect this need.  Thanks.

Comment: @pylang - if you can match the whole invalid "2;a", you can get around this situation by only requiring single character lookarounds: (?<=^|\s)[^(\[]*;[^)\]]*(?=\s|$)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Makes sense to match all non-delimiters around `;`.  However, the last example seems to miss `(2;a` or `2;a)` cases, which also do not contain `;`.  I'm not sure why.